# CKEDITOR 4 How to make snapshot before using custom command to use CTRL+Z to undo

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Problem is following:

We have custom block element, such as quote.

We want to have a possibility to "CTRL+Z" (Undo) its creation.

How to make snapshot of current state of ckeditor before inserting its html, so CTRL+Z after that would be usable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To save a snapshot just fire [`saveSnapshot`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-saveSnapshot) event on editor instance. You have to do this before and after performing an action which should be recorded as a separate snapshot. For example:

```
editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
editor.insertHtml( '...' );
editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
```

Also, if your functionality is a single command, remember that editor records snapshots whenever you execute it. So **this wouldn't make sense**:

```
editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
editor.execCommand( 'myCmd' );
editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
```

**Update**: If you want to merge some operations which could make their own snapshots (like executed command) then you can lock snapshot before performing them and unlock after.

```
editor.fire( 'lockSnapshot' );
editor.execCommand( 'myCmd1' );
editor.execCommand( 'myCmd2' );
editor.fire( 'unlockSnapshot' );
```

While snapshot is locked new snapshots won't be recorder. If snapshot stack was up to date in the moment of locking the snapshot, then `unlockSnapshot` will update the last snapshot. But if it wasn't then all those changes will not be recorded until next `saveSnapshot` is fired.

This is a bit tricky and requires some practice and testing to start using this mechanism properly :).

Comment: what if I want to do sequence: snapshot -> exec my command -> insert html -> snapshot. Is it possible to undo whole operation by crtl+z ?

Comment: I would try this today and accept answer if success, thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much. Managed to make my toolbar fully usable by adding Undo/Redo to it :)